# flask/python: best way to import and parse a sqlite file

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

At my work we frequently work with sqlite files to perform troubleshooting. I want to create a web page, possibly in flask, that allows users to upload a .sqlite file and automatically have simple, pre-defined queries run.

What is the best way within a Flask application to import a .sqlite file, run queries on it, and then set itself up to repeat the process?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use an sqlite file with specific queries is using `sqlite3` package, Just:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('PATH TO FILE')
result = db.execute(query, args)
...
```

Comment: ah awesome, that's really easy. so presumably, I could just stick that in a flask view and call it a day.

Comment: is there a best practice for teardown after you obtain the result?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to upload that file to the server, to do so, you can start reading this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/
Then, you can connect to that .sqlite file like this, and then execute queries:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/your/sqlite_file')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('my query')
cursor.fetchall() # If you used a select statement
# OR
connection.commit() # If you inserted date for example
```